# Not able to use .not() or :not properly

Tags: javascript, jquery

Why am I not able to add `.red` class to the `.out` but exclude the first closest?

```js
$('.ring').on('click', function() {

  $(this).not().closest('out').addClass('red');
});
```

```css
div {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  float: left;
  margin: 2px;
}

.ring {
  background: grey;
}

.out {
  background: khaki;
}

.red {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="map">
  <div class="data">
    <div class="ring"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="out"></div>
</div>
<div class="map">
  <div class="data">
    <div class="ring"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="out"></div>
</div>
<div class="map">
  <div class="data">
    <div class="ring"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="out"></div>
</div>
<div class="map">
  <div class="data">
    <div class="ring"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="out"></div>
</div>
<div class="map">
  <div class="data">
    <div class="ring"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="out"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: `not()` needs something passed to it, and you passed the wrong value to `closest()`, ie you didn't use a proper css selector eg `.out`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it using the `index` like this:

```js
$('.ring').on('click', function() {
  $(".red").removeClass("red");
  var index = $(".ring").index(this);  
  $(".out").not(":eq("+index+")").addClass('red');
});
```

```css
div {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  float: left;
  margin: 2px;
}

.ring {
  background: grey;
}

.out {
  background: khaki;
}

.red {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="map">
  <div class="data">
    <div class="ring"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="out"></div>
</div>
<div class="map">
  <div class="data">
    <div class="ring"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="out"></div>
</div>
<div class="map">
  <div class="data">
    <div class="ring"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="out"></div>
</div>
<div class="map">
  <div class="data">
    <div class="ring"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="out"></div>
</div>
<div class="map">
  <div class="data">
    <div class="ring"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="out"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd add the red class to everything then remove it from the adjacent element.  You're not quite using the [not](http://api.jquery.com/not/) function correctly.

This solution uses parents to go up the tree from the selected element until it finds the map, then does a `find` to identify the `.out` underneath that parent:

```
// add red class to all elements with .out
$('.out').addClass('red');
// remove red from out under parent .map
$(this).parents('.map').find('.out').removeClass('red');
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using `closest` incorrectly. `out` is not a ascendant of `ring`. You need to traverse up to parent and get all siblings

```
$(this).closest('.map').nextAll(':not(:first)').find('.out').addClass('red')
```

Remove `:not(:first)` if you want to next element to be colored as well